# Repositories in gradle project were not indexed

Tags: maven, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to synchronize a gradle project with some dependences to Spring Boot and Maven, but there is an error that indicates the following repositories used in the project are not indexed yet:

> Unindexed remote maven repositories found.
>
> The following repositories used in your gradle projects were not
> indexed yet:
>
> http://repo.spring.io/milestone
>
> http://repo.spring.io/snapshot
>
> https://repo1.maven.org/maven2
>
> https://plugins.gradle.org/m2
>
> If you want to use dependency completion for these repositories
> artifacts, Open Repositories List, select required repositories and press "Update" button.

Then I'm trying to update the remote repositories manually, but I'm getting an error while I trying to do.

[image]

Any know what can I do to resolve the issue?

I'm using **IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.6** and the **gradle version is 2.2**, I leave the `build.gradle` file of the project with the dependencies that I use.

```
group 'com.scl.boot'
version '0.5'

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'groovy'
    apply plugin: 'war'
    apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
    apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
    apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.cargo'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
            maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
            maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.7.RELEASE'
            classpath 'org.sonarqube.gradle:gradle-sonarqube-plugin:1.1'
            classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-cargo-plugin:2.2.1'
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        
        compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
        compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging'
        compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
        compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-rest', version: '1.3.6.RELEASE'

        compile 'org.jsondoc:spring-boot-starter-jsondoc:1.2.9'
        compile 'org.jsondoc:jsondoc-ui-webjar:1.2.9'
        
        compile 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc'
        compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-oracle:1.2.1.RELEASE'
        
        compile group: 'cn.easyproject', name: 'ojdbc7', version: '12.1.0.2.0'

        compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jdbc-core', version: '1.2.1.RELEASE'
        
        compile 'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-dbcp:8.0.28'
        
        compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.+'
        
        compile 'org.op4j:op4j-jodatime:1.1'
        
        compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:1.3.0.M2'
        
        compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.7'
        compile 'org.json:json:20151123'
        
        compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
        
        compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all'
        
        compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.8.3'
        compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.3'
        compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-xml', version: '2.8.3'


       
        cargo 'org.jboss.as:jboss-as-controller-client:7.2.0.Final'
        compile group: 'org.codehaus.cargo', name: 'cargo-core-uberjar', version: '1.5.0'
        cargo 'org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-ant:1.4.16'

        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
        testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:1.2.7.RELEASE'
        testCompile group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-core', version: '1.0-groovy-2.4'
    }


    war {
        archiveName = "CyCRest.war"
        configurations {
            runtime.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
            runtime.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
        }
    }
```

[EDIT] This is the `idea.log` file with the exceptions that I'm getting:

> java.io.IOException: Transfer for nexus-maven-repository-index.gz
> failed

[Download the log file.](https://safenote.co/r/5e25d121c49f48@02852746)

Comment: Please provide idea.log (Help | Show Log in ... action) after IDE restart and trying to index repositories.

Comment: @Andrey I leave it at the final of the question, btw already tried restarting the IDE several times.